# Xamarin.Forms Intellisense not Working Inside Grid, Stacklayout element

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, intellisense

I am working with VS 2015 with Update 2, Xamarin 4.2.0.703. Please see attached file.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like the IntelliSense you _do_ get isn't right either.. Try the following: Right click the XAML file in the solution explorer and click 'Open With...' then select the 'Source Code (Text) Editor' and set is as Default. To be sure restart Visual Studio altogether and see if it works then.

Comment: I have already set XAML File set as Text Editor but Intellisense not working here... i have repaired visual studio also.

Comment: Did you also update Xamarin to the latest version? Also I notice you say you have VS Update 2, maybe try to upgrade to Update 3?

Comment: Thanks for guide.i will install Update3...

Comment: Xamarin Instellisense not working inside grid,stacklayout still...

Comment: I am having the same issue. Also inside C# files I have to type the package name or the package has to be imported prior to it gets shown up inside statements.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a regression in VS2015. And you can read the discussion at https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/46185/visual-studio-2015-intellisense-regression-when-editing-xaml-files.

I got it working by replacing dlls inside /packages/xamarin.forms.xxx/lib/ on each platform.

Couldn't get the permalink to the answer so am quoting it.

> In the meantime you can try this[1] to bring back XF IntelliSense
>   until XF releases an official fix.
>
> [1] http://xvs.xamarin.com/Xamarin.Forms.Intellisense.zip

Zip has a readme with detailed fix.